# I need to get the difference between two time stamps when I post comment on the page

Tags: php, post, timestamp

```
 <?php
 session_start();

  function time_stamp($session_time) 
  { 
  $session_time=new DateTime();
  $post_time=new DateTime();
  $time_difference = date_diff($post_time,$session_time); 
  $time_difference->format('y-m-d h-m-s');
  $seconds = $time_difference ; 
  $minutes = round($time_difference / 60 ); //line 11
  $hours = round($time_difference / 3600 ); //line 12
  $days = round($time_difference / 86400 ); //line 13
  $weeks = round($time_difference / 604800 ); //line 14
  $months = round($time_difference / 2419200 ); //line 15
  $years = round($time_difference / 29030400 ); //line 16

  if($seconds <= 60)
  {
  echo"$seconds seconds ago";  //line 18
  }
   else if($minutes <=60)
  {
  if($minutes==1)
   {
   echo"one minute ago"; 
   }
  else
   {
   echo"$minutes minutes ago"; 
   }
     ?>
```

I am trying to get the difference between two timestamps i.e when the post was posted and current time.
When I submit my post it should show  posted x seconds/minutes/weeks ago

ERROR MESSAGE

Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 11
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in
C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 12
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 13
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 14
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 15
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 16
Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 18
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\home.php on line 20

Comment: It seems as though you've fundamentally misunderstood what `date_diff` returns. As the error itself clearly states, it's a [`DateInterval` object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and you're treating as though it's a simple number.

Comment: `$time_difference` is not an integer. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#97880 Might be what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DateInterval::format ( string $format ) : string
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

The format function (line 10), will return a string , so I'm not sure why you're using that to get the `$seconds`

Instead, `date_diff` returns a DateInterval object, so you should look at the php docs for DateInterval
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

And you may notice that it has some properties such as: `$y`, `$m`, etc.
So what you should do is actually something like `$time_difference->s`.